# Magento 2: Add 2 JS files in that depend on each other in checkout page

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend, requirejs-config.js

I tried to add 2 js files in checkout page using `require-config.js` from a custom extension like this:

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": { 
            'GAP': 'Vendor_Module/js/gap',
            'GAP-PICKER': 'Vendor_Module/js/gap-picker-min'
        }
    } 
};
```

The `gap.js` and `gap-picker-min.js` are located under `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js`, the `gap-picker-min.js` will be depended on `gap.js` , but when i tried to call the GAP function like this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'GAP',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/customer-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address',
    'GAP-PICKER'
], function ($,GAP, ko, Component, quote, shippingService, rateRegistry, customerAddressProcessor, newAddressProcessor) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
          console.log(GAP);
```

it shows undefined